# Get how many times a task has been rescheduled

Tags: org-mode

I'm trying to get how many times a task has been re-scheduled (the `Sched.00x:` you see in org-agenda for "today tasks"). But so far, I don't know how to extract information from the structure returned by `org-agenda-get-day-entries`.

My original plan was to regexp the hell out of the title, since it carries the information I'm looking, but I don't even know how to obtain from the data structure for the title of the entry. It doesn't seems like the number of times an entry was re-scheduled comes within the data structure.

This is my current code:

```
(let* ((files (org-agenda-files))
         (due-todos 0)
         (due-older 0)
         (today (calendar-current-date)))
    (dolist (file files)
      (let* ((entries (org-agenda-get-day-entries file today :scheduled :deadline)))
        (dolist (entry entries)
          ;; Get how many times the task was re-scheduled, and count it
          ))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggesting another approach since `org-agenda-get-day-entries` parses more than you asked for:

```el
(let (res)
  (dolist (i org-agenda-files)
    (with-current-buffer (get-file-buffer i)
      (org-with-wide-buffer
       (goto-char (point-min))
       (while (re-search-forward org-heading-regexp nil t)
         (push (cons
                (match-string-no-properties 2)
                (- (org-today) (time-to-days (org-get-scheduled-time (point)))))
               res)))))
  (seq-filter (lambda (x) (> (cdr x) 0)) res))
```

Alternatively, to retrieve the `Sched.00x:` strings, use `get-text-property`:

```el
(mapcar (lambda (x) (get-text-property 0 'extra x))
        (org-agenda-get-day-entries
         file
         (calendar-current-date) :scheduled))
```

Comment: isn't better to let `org-agenda-get-day-entries` do the hard work of parsing the files? I don't mind if the function returns more information than I'm asking, I would like to know how to manipulate and extract the stuff is inside it.